# Find the value of $f'(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a countinuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and twice differentiable for all $x\neq0$, and assume  $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ exists.

1. Find the value of $f'(0)$
2. Is $f''(0)$ always exists in general? i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}/f(x)x^n$ for $n>3$?

For the first question, by L'Hopital's rule, I know it equals to $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f'(x)}{3x^2}$$
and I want to have $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f'(x)$ exist, then it can be used to prove the limit of $f'(0)$ exist. But I don't know how to say it does exist mathematically.

Or can we just use the below defination to find the value? $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h^3} h^2=0$$(So is the left limit）

For the second question, I think it doesn't always exist. Simply we can find the counterexample with the term $sin(\frac{1}{x})$, because we cannot cancel the $1/x$, is it correct for $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)/x^n$?

Can someone help me with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're absolutely on the right track! By assumption, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}=L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{3x^2}$ for some $L\in \mathbb{R}$. From this you can conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=0$ and since $f'$ is continuous, $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=f'(0)$.

Comment: Also, for the second question you are on the right track! You can create explicit counterexamples.

Comment: Why do you insist $x\neq 0$ for continuity? And next mention that it is twice differentiable which would imply that it is continuous at $x=0$. Note that without continuity at $0$ we can't really figure out $f(0),f'(0),f''(0)$.

Comment: Perhaps you need to remove that statement about continuity and just mention that it is twice everywhere. But this makes your second question irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry it should be differentiable at any nonzero $x$, will edit it now, thanks

Comment: Even in that case you can't say that $f'(0)$ exists or not. Without the value of $f(0)$ you can't think about derivatives at $0$.

Comment: Also LHospital Rule can't be used here.

Comment: ooh yes, I click the previous edit by mistake, it should be continuous everywhere but non-differentiable at 0. Thanks

Comment: Please state your assumptions clearly in questions. Here is what works: if $f $ is continuous at $0$ and $f(x) /x^3$ tends to a limit as $x\to 0$ then $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

Comment: You can't conclude anything about $f''(0)$ from the given conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right track! By assumption, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}=L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{3x^2}$ for some $L\in \mathbb{R}$. From this you can conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=0$ (we'll prove this below) and since $f'$ is continuous, $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=f'(0)$.

Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ exists as $f'$ is continuous. Assume that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=a$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Then $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{3x^2}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0}3x^2}=\frac{a}{0}=\pm \infty.$$
This is a contradiction! Thus $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=0$.

**Edit:** Whoops I only now read that $f$ is not $C^2$ everywhere! That means this argument needs to be adapted!

**Second edit:** Nevermind, the OP included the assumption that $f$ is twice differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, they are the same as $C^2$, for the second one, is $f''(0)$ always exist and $f'(0)=0$ in general?